# Flutter SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal) within another SingleChildScrollView(Vertical)

Tags: flutter

How can I make the Flutter SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal) within another SingleChildScrollView(Vertical) code attached here below work?

I am getting the following exception:

Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: _RenderScrollSemantics#0e053:
needs compositing
creator: _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#35899] ← Scrollable ← SingleChildScrollView ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#364d1] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← ⋯
parentData:  (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(w=414.0, h=896.0)
semantic boundary
size: MISSING
Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.
A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
#0      RenderBox.hitTest. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:9)
#1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2401:6)
#2      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (p<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: _RenderScrollSemantics#0e053:
needs compositing
creator: _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#35899] ← Scrollable ← SingleChildScrollView ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#364d1] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← ⋯
parentData:  (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(w=414.0, h=896.0)
semantic boundary
size: MISSING
Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.
A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
#0      RenderBox.hitTest. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:9)
#1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2401:6)
#2      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (p<…>

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grid Demo'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Grid(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 200),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Grid extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Positioned> getUnits() {
    double _unitRadius = 50;
    List<Positioned> _units = [];
    double _leftCoordinate = 0;
    double _bottomCoordinate = 0;
    double _margin = 5;
    double _stepFromLeft = _unitRadius + _margin;
    double _stepFromBottom = _unitRadius + _margin;

    int _maxColumns = 10;
    int _maxRows = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < _maxRows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < _maxColumns; j++) {
        _units.add(Positioned(
            bottom: _bottomCoordinate,
            left: _leftCoordinate,
            child: Container(
              width: _unitRadius,
              height: _unitRadius,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('$i $j')),
            )));
        _leftCoordinate += _stepFromLeft;
      }
      _leftCoordinate = 0;
      _bottomCoordinate += _stepFromBottom;
    }

    return _units;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: getUnits(),
    );
  }
}

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double blockSizeHorizontal;
  static double blockSizeVertical;
  static double _safeAreaHorizontal;
  static double _safeAreaVertical;
  static double safeBlockHorizontal;
  static double safeBlockVertical;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth;
    blockSizeVertical = screenHeight;
    _safeAreaHorizontal =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.left + _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
    _safeAreaVertical =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.top + _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;

    safeBlockHorizontal = (screenWidth - _safeAreaHorizontal);
    safeBlockVertical = (screenHeight - _safeAreaVertical);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the vertical singlechildscrollview in a container, and set the width and height of this container to screen width and height. On the other hand it's more appropriate if you use ListView for horizontal scrolling, or ListView.builder if your items are of same types

```
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap:      true,
    children: <Widget>[
        //your widget items here
    ],
),
```

Comment: this method is not working, it is giving the same exception as before!

Comment: I just edited my post, could you try this please

Comment: could you specifically mention which part in the code I have attached to wrap the ListView? Because I am still getting errors!

Answer (score 0):

Here Your SingleChildScrollView items will scroll in vertically and ListView.builder items will draw items horizontally, (by default), in case of list view builder you need to fix a specific/dynamic height to avoid errors.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
          height: 100,
             child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: ...),
              ),
            )
```

& in your code, use :

```
   Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```

Comment: could you please give me an example with reference to the attached code. Thank you